# How to fill data safety?

Tags: android, admob, ads, google-play-console

I am filling in the Google Play Data Safety form for my app. My app uses AdMob and no other libraries that collect info about the user. How should I fill it in?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Your best resource for this type of question will be [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/play-data-disclosure) itself - which has a page about this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a policy question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For AdMob:

Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types? Yes
Is all of the user data collected by your app encrypted in transit? Yes
Do you provide a way for users to request that their data is deleted? No

Location > Approximate location
App activity > App interactions
App info and performance > Crash logs, Diagnostics
Device or other identifiers > Device or other identifiers

Is this data collected, shared, or both? Shared
Is this data processed ephemerally? No
Is this data required for your app, or can users choose whether it’s collected? Data collection is required (users can’t turn off this data collection)
Why is this user data shared? Advertising or marketing

Comment: How do you know that data in transit is encrypted? Google didn't provide answer to this question yet, both in docs, neither on forums f.e. https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/2So-N4qi2xE

Comment: @ufoq you can see in the documentation. They have mentioned "All of the user data collected by Google Mobile Ads SDK is encrypted in transit using the Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol." https://developers.google.com/admob/android/play-data-disclosure#data_collected_and_shared_automatically

Comment: Do I still need to choose Approximate location if I've not put permission in manifest xml ?

Comment: Yes you have to because Admob uses it, you can find it in it's website. https://developers.google.com/admob/android/play-data-disclosure